# The Mysqli extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded

Tags: php, zend-framework, mysqli

An application buid in Zend framework was working fine when it was in demo server.
I moved the site to clients server, then I am facing following issue. Please help me to fix 
this issue.

Thanks.

================ BEGIN Error

```
exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli_Exception' with message 'The Mysqli extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded' in 
Stack Trase

/home/mtapp/public_html/demo/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Mysqli.php:291
0 /home/mtapp/public_html/demo/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(448): Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli->_connect()
1 /home/mtapp/public_html/demo/library/Entity/Page.php(119): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT p.slug, ...')
2 /home/mtapp/public_html/demo/modules/site/controllers/ErrorController.php(23): Entity_Page::getMenuItems()
3 /home/mtapp/public_html/demo/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): Site_ErrorController->errAction()
4 /home/mtapp/public_html/demo/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(289): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('errAction')
5 /home/mtapp/public_html/demo/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
6 /home/mtapp/public_html/demo/Bootstrap.php(21): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
7 /home/mtapp/public_html/demo/public/index.php(7): Bootstrap::run()
8 {main}
```

================ END Error

Comment: Are you sure the mysqli extension for php is installed? The error message indicates that there's a problem relating to it on your server. If you're not sure, the following code <?php phpinfo(); ?> should tell you if it is or not

Comment: Or just switch the adapter and connection details to PDO. Youre going to need one or the other installed though.

Answer (score 0):

If you using an old version of socialengine then switch to PHP v5.6.